# How to plot a large number of vbar in a Bokeh figure

Tags: bokeh

Hi I am trying to modify the example code here

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/bar_mixed.html

I removed the toolbar_location=None so that the Bokeh toolbar can show, also I made factors array very large.

I would like to see a figure that I can pan/scroll to view more data rather than it is doing right now-congested all the bars in the fixed width.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version `0.12.16` Bokeh only supports initially showing all the factors. There is no mechanism to show only some subset. You can open a GitHub issue if you would like to discuss adding this as a feature.